# resize partitions

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize primary partition](https://superuser.com/questions/52817/resize-primary-partition)

I have 2 partitions on my disk. I want to expand the system partition  `C` at the disk start and reduce the 2nd partition `D` to make the space to expand `C`.

[image: Disk]

How can I do that? (I would prefer OS Tools or Freeware)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html) did the trick and is free.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the 2nd partition (the D: drive), select "Shrink Volume", set the amount of space to shrink the partition by.

[Quick video on getting to the "Shrink Volume" tool.](http://screencast.com/t/z7LSBPNFpgK)

Right-click on the first partition (the C: drive), select "Extend Volume", set it to the amount you want and your done.

Comment: I know about that function. But if I shrink `D` would the free space be at the **end** of the disk? In that case I can't resize `C` with that space, right?